# Наложение одного DIV элемента на другой DIV элемент без смещения

Tags: position, z-index, display

Доброго времени суток. Никак не удается наложить один див на другой.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(
function () {
    $(".log-in").click(
        function () {
            $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
            return false;
        }
    )
}
);

</script>
```

```css
<style> 
.panel {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.layer2 {
  position: static;
  z-index: 1;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div style="width: 1025px; margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0">
  <div style="background-image: url(http://i10.pixs.ru/storage/7/5/2/receipts21_2931070_21219752.jpg); width: 1025px; height: 90px; float: left"></div>
  <div style="background-image: url(http://i10.pixs.ru/storage/7/7/9/receipts22_1063973_21219779.jpg); width: 210px; height: 160px; float: left"></div>

  <div class="log-in" style="background-image: url(http://i9.pixs.ru/storage/7/8/4/receipts23_5019003_21219784.jpg); width: 599px; height: 160px; float: left">
    <img src="http://i9.pixs.ru/storage/7/8/4/receipts23_5019003_21219784.jpg">
  </div>

  <div style="background-image: url(http://i9.pixs.ru/storage/8/0/0/receipts24_2944699_21219800.jpg); width: 216px; height: 160px; float: right"></div>

  <div class="layer2" style="background-image: url(http://i10.pixs.ru/storage/7/5/2/receipts21_2931070_21219752.jpg); width: 1025px; height: 90px; float: left"></div>

  <!---Выплывающий див, содержащий блочные элементы. Выше есть стили для него.--->
  
  <div class="panel">
    <div style="background-image: url(http://i11.pixs.ru/storage/9/5/2/nw01jpg_6250693_21219952.jpg); width: 1025px; height: 46px; float: left"></div>
    <div style="background-image: url(http://i9.pixs.ru/storage/9/5/9/nw02jpg_3216711_21219959.jpg); width: 381px; height: 19px; float: left"></div>
    <div style="background-image: url(http://i9.pixs.ru/storage/9/6/8/nw03jpg_4817510_21219968.jpg); width: 246px; height: 19px; float: left"></div>
    <div style="background-image: url(http://i9.pixs.ru/storage/9/7/7/nw04jpg_4266368_21219977.jpg); width: 398px; height: 19px; float: left"></div>
    <div style="background-image: url(http://i10.pixs.ru/storage/9/8/3/nw05jpg_3552795_21219983.jpg); width: 1025px; height: 45px; float: left"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

http://i9.pixs.ru/storage/7/8/4/receipts23_5019003_21219784.jpg

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Пример должен быть понятным и воспроизводимым.

Comment: ну как бы много лишнего будет если весь код сюда копирну, а что именно непонятно в вопросе?

Comment: Замени чем-нибудь несуществующие картинки. Размести стили в соответствующем блоке сниппета. Удали не имеющие отношения стили. Остальные отправь в css. Поясни, какие и как именно блоки должны накладываться. Нужен ли js-код и как он связан с вопросом?

Comment: понял, будет сделано в теч. 10 минут

Comment: за 10 как всегда не вышло ))

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v2jsyL7k/

Comment: отображается на jsfiddle "в развернутом виде" но я добавил еще на хостинг http://pm-ocenka.ru/block.html, при нажатии на картинку где знак письма выплывает див, но он не накладывается на тот который внизу. В этом и состоит задача. Извини если не ясно излагаю.

Comment: Фиддл не работает.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/otkambasok/j5spp40r/ заработал

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оба блока "заворачиваем" в еще один блок с `position:relative`

А для указанных блоков меняем в стилях `position:absolute` и добавляем позиционирование `top:0`

В этом случае внутренние блоки абсолютно позиционируются относительно внешнего.

Comment: Работает как положено, спасибо, теперь разобрался